# On `tty <&1` vs `echo $(tty <&1)` vs `echo $(tty <&2)`

Tags: tty, stdout, file-descriptors

The key statements in the snippet below (i.e. other than those for printing labels and blank lines, for spacing) come in pairs.  In each pair, the first and second statements have the forms `tty...` and `echo $(tty...)`, respectively.

```bsh
echo stdin:
tty
echo $(tty)

echo

echo stdout:
tty <&1
echo $(tty <&1)

echo

echo stderr:
tty <&2
echo $(tty <&2)
```

If I source a file containing this snippet (in a `zsh` or `bash` session, for example), I get the following output<sup>1</sup> (I added the line numbers afterwards, for reference):

```
 1    stdin:
 2    /dev/pts/8
 3    /dev/pts/8
 4    
 5    stdout:
 6    /dev/pts/8
 7    not a tty
 8    
 9    stderr:
10    /dev/pts/8
11    /dev/pts/8
```

In this output, the line generated by `echo $(tty <&1)` (line 7) sticks out conspicuously, for two reasons:

1. it is the only one among the `echo $(tty ...)`-generated lines (namely, lines 3, 7, and 11) that differs its `tty ...`-generated counterpart, immediately preceding it (lines 2, 6, and 10); and
2. it differs from the output (line 11) of the formally analogous `echo $(tty <&2)`.

**Q:** How are these two discrepancies explained?

---

For the record, I tried to find the explanation for these apparent anomalies in the manual page for `tty`, but, as far as I can tell, this page does not address these questions at all<sup>2</sup>; certainly not explicitly<sup>3</sup>.

This question was motivated by some of the code [this great answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/672209/10618) to an earlier question of mine.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>Of course, the actual number after `/dev/pts/` will be different if I change terminals, and will likely be different for you if you try the same thing.</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup>In fact, the entire DESCRIPTION section of the `tty` manual page available on my system consists of just one sentence: "Print the file name of the terminal connected to standard input.".</sup>

<sup><sup>3</sup>Here I am leaving open the possibility that someone with more background knowledge than I have may be able to *deduce* from `tty`'s terse manual page the behavior illustrated above.</sup>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`tty` reports (on its stdout) the name of tty device that is opened on its standard input (its fd 0).

In:

```
tty <&2
```

Which is short for

```
tty 0<&2
```

The shell redirects fd 0 to the same resource as is open on fd 2 (does a `dup2(2, 0)` in a new process and then runs `tty` in that process. So `tty` will have the same resource on its fd 0 and 2 and write on fd 1 the tty that is open on both (if any).

Same happens with:

```
tty <&1
```

In:

```
echo "$(tty <&1)"
```

however, fd 1 of that command substitution goes to a pipe (and the shell reads what `tty` outputs at the other end), it's not the same resource as where the fd 1 of `echo` goes to.

If you want to know what tty is open on fd 1 and use a command substitution, you'd need something like:

```
{ echo "$(tty <&3)"; } 3<&1
```

So for the process running `tty`, we have:

- 3: same as the outer 1
- 1: a pipe
- 2: untouched
- 0: same as 3, so same as outer 1

So `tty` can write to that pipe the path of the tty device that is connected to the *outer* stdout.

As tty doesn't need that fd 3, you can make it a bit cleaner with:

```
{ echo "$(tty <&3 3<&-)"; } 3<&1
```

That is, close it after you've used it to duplicate it to fd 0.